# How to make redis database connection with python webapp on heroku

Tags: python, heroku, redis

I created a web app with Redis as a database, Its running fine on local But when I'm deploying it on Heroku its giving error.
I've already created Redis addon trying to create Redis server instance with credentials provided by Heroku. How to make sure that Redis server is running on Heroku or not?

```
import redis

# Localhost
redis = redis.Redis('localhost') #working fine on localhost

#heroku
redis = redis.Redis('redis://user:password@host:port')
# throwing error connecting to redis://user:password@host:port. Name or service not known.
```

Comment: You will have to put in the a actual hostname and credentials instead of the placeholders.

Comment: @KlausD. can you tell me what will be the actual parameters need to be passed, please write the format if possible

Comment: That is what **you** have to know. It would be weired if I'd know your credentials.

Comment: NO, I'm taliking about parameters

Comment: red = redis.StrictRedis.from_url('redis://user:password@host:port') for Heorku, red = redis.StrictRedis.from_url("redis://localhost") for localhost. Then you simply read the URL from an environment variable.